# jQuery is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is wrong with this statement?

```
message = $("#contact-form").find(".long-text");

if(message.val().length < 15)
{
    message.css("border","2px solid red");
    alert("Your message must be more than 15 character long");
}
```

I get message.val is not a function error in [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28Firefox_extension%29)? What could be the reason?

**NEW**

OK, now my form won't submit if I have more or less than 15 characters. Should I open a new question on this or should I continue on this one?

I have this inside:

```
$("#contact-form").submit(function(){
  message = $("#contact-form").find(".long-text");

    if(message.val().length < 15)
    {
        message.css("border","2px solid red");
        alert("Your message must be more than 15 character long");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        Post form with Ajax ..
    }
});
```

Comment: Each independent question is supposed to have its own thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the syntax highlighter, the quotes went bogus :) There's a doublequote missing.

Besides, the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) only works on `input` elements (`input`, `select`, `textarea` and `button`). If it is indeed not an `input` element, then rather use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead. Further there's no such function as `length()`, you probably would like to use the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property.

I recommend to go get yourself through some basic [jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) and/or to go get a [jQuery book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988355).

Answer (score 0):

Besides missing the end quote delimiter, here are some other notes

- `length` is a property, not a method. It should be `message.val().length`
- `val()` is also only useful for HTML input elements. You could try `message.html().length` or use `text()`, depending on your requirements

Answer (score 0):

How about .length instead of length()

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```
message = $("#contact-form").find(".long-text").first();
```